# Unkown column in 'on clause' when using IFNULL and ALIAS

Tags: mysql

The reason I'm using `IFNULL` is to change null fields to 0. But I always get this error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'inc.month_id' in 'on clause'

Here's my Mysql query:

```
    SELECT * FROM tbl_month
left joins 
(
   select ifnull(tbl_income.rentals,0) as rentals, ifnull(tbl_income.electric,0) as electric, ifnull(tbl_income.month_id,0) as month_id
   from tbl_income 
   where tbl_income.igp_id = 1
) as inc on tbl_month.month_id = inc.month_id;
```

EDIT: I added all columns manually but null fields are not replaced by 0s.

OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: You can't do `ifnull('*',0)` this way, you have to list all the columns and put `ifnull` for each one, this is not valid syntax.

Comment: Give each column an alias like what the answers below suggested `select ifnull(tbl_income.rentals,0) AS month_id, ...`

Comment: What is the error you got? note that: `left joins` should be `left join` or this is a typo in the question?

Comment: please see the attached image

Comment: @MahmoudGamal can i give you the mysql database? I really need your help.

Comment: You can also setup a demo in this site [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with the tables and tell me what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because of the `left join`; either use `inner join` or put the `ifnull` in the main select not in the subquery:

```
SELECT 
  ifnull(inc.rentals,0) as rentals, 
  ifnull(inc.electric,0) as electric, 
  ifnull(inc.month_id,0) as month_id,
  ...
FROM tbl_month t1
left join tbl_income as inc on t1.month_id = inc.month_id;
```

Comment: thanks. What I did is to move the `ifnull` in the main select statement.

Comment: @JaysonTamayo - You're welcome any time :) Glad I could help :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem you have is that you do not named the column in temporary table 'inc'.

You have this

`ifnull('*',0)`

but should have

`ifnull('*',0) as month_id`.

NOTE:

That `ifnull('*',0)` will result always with `'*'`.

If you want to validate only `month_id` columns you must do it like this

`ifnull(month_id,0) as month_id`

Comment: @Johan, That how SQL works. The result will be always '*', but this is another story.

Comment: The answer is slightly better, but instead of just correcting the answer it is now confusing. and the sentence: `should have ifnull('*',0) as month_id.` makes no sense. The alias is not the problem here, not referencing the column is the problem. Anyway the question has shifted, so the `'*'` issue does not link to anything anymore....